# How to delete certain rows depending on group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, delete-row

I have a tricky question. I need to **delete rows from a table, but only those that are not the maximum entry in a group**. Here is an example:
Group is (Month, Fruit).

```
Month      | Fruit  | Quantity
2013-01-01 | Apple  | 5
2013-02-01 | Apple  | 6
2013-03-01 | Apple  | 7
2013-03-01 | Apple  | 8
2013-01-01 | Banana | 5
2013-02-01 | Banana | 6
2013-02-01 | Banana | 7
```

The correct transition would be (only the highest quantity should stay in each Month+Fruit group):

```
Month      | Fruit  | Quantity
2013-01-01 | Apple  | 5
2013-02-01 | Apple  | 6
2013-03-01 | Apple  | 8
2013-01-01 | Banana | 5
2013-02-01 | Banana | 7
```

(I actually need to have a full calendar-fruit table, for every fruit for every month. So if you manage to do it with adding a 2013-03 Banana,  it is not a problem, it is a plus.)

Table is a declared variable `@tempTable` , deleting from that directly is preferred. I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This table have a primary key?

Comment: @AndrewPaes it can be solved without even knowing that.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but with a PK this have a easy way ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit, Month ORDER BY Quantity DESC)
  FROM @tempTable
)
SELECT * FROM x
--DELETE x 
WHERE rn > 1;
```

When you are satisfied that the result identifies the correct rows that you want to delete, get rid of the SELECT and uncomment the DELETE.

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdba62/1)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I wasn't sure, if the sample output in the question was what he wanted deleted, or what he wanted to remain.